# Opencv Imgcodecs.imread UnsatisfiedLinkError with Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, opencv, playframework, java-native-interface

I am calling opencv's Imgcodecs.imread in one of play frameworks controller, but its giving me UnsatisfiedLinkError. Calling this

```
Imgcodecs.imread("/path/to/image.jpg")
```

and get this error

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:463)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:111)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:110)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:110)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:103)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:118)
    at controllers.ImageToolController$$anonfun$index$1.apply(ImageToolController.scala:52)
    at controllers.ImageToolController$$anonfun$index$1.apply(ImageToolController.scala:48)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:371)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:370)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:498)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:495)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:458)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
```

The funny part is the same call works from an object that extends App.

```
object Main extends App {

    Imgcodecs.imread("/path/to/image.jpg")
}
```

I am using sbt to run the play server as well the above object. One works, one doesnt.

I am making the call to load the libopencv_java320.dylib library

```
System.load("/path/to/opencv/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_java320.dylib")
```

I am not sure whats causing this anomaly.

Comment: Play handles several classloaders due to dev mode, it may cause some issue with how opencv is registered. Try to run your application from `sbt stage` to confirm that the issue comes from different classloaders

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried `sbt stage`, but its throwing `Error: Could not find or load main class play.core.server.ProdServerStart` when I run the jar  generated with it. I generated the jar using `sbt assembly`, and it still gives me the same error. Any other ideas

Comment: With `sbt stage`, did you run your app with `target/universal/stage/bin/<your-app>` ?

Comment: No I hadnt. Just tried it. Still the same error.